# Apollo subscription is not working on the client side

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

I have an app with graphql server and with vue on the client side. There's a chat there, and I want to do something when a new message appears. I have a subscription for it, and everything's fine on the server side. However, when I tried to connect it to the front-end, I get no results from the subscription, just null. 
Here's the subscription from my queries file:

```js
export const MESSAGEADDED = gql `
subscription($user: ID!) {
    messageAdded(user: $user){
        _id
        text
        createdAt
        user {
            _id
            username
            avatar_link
        }
    }
}
`
```

Here's a part of the apollo section of my chat module:

```js
 apollo: {
    $subscribe:{
      tagAdded:{
        query: MESSAGEADDED,
        variables(){
          return{
             user: this.$store.getters.user._id
          }
        },
        result({data}){
          this.$apollo.queries.messages.refetch()
         

        }
      }
    }
```

I only get null from graphql in the dev tools in the network section.
When I use graphql playground, for example, and insert the query directly, I get the results.

Does anyone have any ideas, what may be wrong?

Comment: Is `this.$store.getters.user._id` defined and the same value you plug into the query when using Playground?

Comment: @DanielRearden Yes, I can see it in the header, it's defined and the same

Comment: If the query and variables are identical, then it has to come down to context. What's your ApolloClient configuration look like, and how is that different from how you've configured Playground?

Comment: @DanielRearden but everything else in the apollo section is working just fine...
The query in the playground looks like this:
subscription {
  messageAdded(user: "..."){
        _id
        text
        createdAt
        user {
            _id
            username
            avatar_link
        }
    }
}